# RPC Server Unavailable error on TestComplete 11

Tags: testcomplete

I am hoping someone here can at least point me in the right direction to solving this frustrating issue.  The smartbear community had no response.

I have a bunch of tests set up in TestComplete to test a web application.  When I run them all at once, I consistently get an RPC Server Unavailable Error.  I have no idea what this means.  When I run the tests individually, there is no issue with the scripts.

I have tried running them in a script, calling them from a keyword test, and just using the project set up to call them all in order.  No dice.  Running each test manually completely defeats the purpose of automation.

Any ideas on how to fix this or at least where the F*** to start??  I did not have this problem with TC10, only when I upgraded to TC11

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be an issue with TestComplete and its Chrome support feature and it is best to contact SmartBear with it (http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete).

Answer (score 0):

So, in each of my modules, I was opening and closing Chrome.  I decided to try taking out the close statement.  Boom, no error.  It still refreshes the page, which is fine.  I don't know why this was a problem, but I got it to run all the modules concurrently